# DAO Design Pattern with Join

Tags: dao

I have a database where we do a lot of requests with join, like this :

```
SELECT A.ID, B.FOO
FROM A
JOIN B ON B.ID=A.ID
WHERE ...
```

My question is : how to apply this request using DAO pattern? Should I put it in, for example, DAOAOracle? Or should I create a new class DAOABOracle? What's the best practice?

Comment: It might be helpful to indicate language and the classes corresponding to tables A and B.

Comment: It's a general question, how to do it on any language and classes A and B are generic (getters, setters, ...)

Answer (score 3):

The DAO pattern is not good with foreign key relationships.

You would need 2 DAO's and read each table separately. That solution could be fine if you don't need to read so many records that it is a performance problem.

You could create a DAO that is for select-only. It would execute the join sql as you have indicated. It would read it into a class that has both A and B columns.

An alternative to DAO's is to use and ORM library. Most ORM's can manage this kind of one-to-one or one-to-many relationships.